# Doxygen & Latex error while creating pdf file

Tags: c++, pdf, latex, doxygen-wizard

Im using the Doxygen GUI to create my documentation under windows. This is my project folder under "D:\Users\Jorge\Desktop\":

```
Pract3Copia+
           |
           +--Documentation (Empty Directory)
           |
           +-- dfa.cpp
           |
           +-- dfa.hpp
           |
           +-- dfa.o
           |
           +-- dfaException.hpp
           |
           +-- dfaException.cpp
           |
           +-- dfaException.o
           |
           +-- state.cpp
           |
           +-- state.hpp
           |
           +-- state.o
           |
           +-- main.cpp
           |
           +-- main.o
           |
           +-- dfa.exe
           |
           +-- Makefile
           |
           +-- 1.dfa
```

Once Doxygen has finished creating the documents, I get this:

```
Documentation+ 
             |
             +-- Latex+ 
                      |
                      +-- annotated.tex
                      |
                      +-- classdfa.tex
                      |
                      +-- classdfa_exceptions.eps
                      |
                      +-- classdfa_exception.tex
                      |
                      +-- classstate.tex
                      |
                      +-- doxygen.sty
                      |
                      +-- hierarchy.tex
                      |
                      +-- make.bat
                      |
                      +-- Makefile
                      |
                      +-- refman.tex
                      |
                      +-- structconnection.tex
```

Now, I proceed to execute "make" command in the cmd. But I'm getting some errors and the .pdf file is not generated. I dont know how this works, so I'm not very sure how should I fix it. I didnt found the error on the internet neither. Thanks.

```
D:\Users\Jorge\Desktop\Pract3-copia\Documentation\latex>make

D:\Users\Jorge\Desktop\Pract3-copia\Documentation\latex>set Dir_Old=D:\Users\Jor
ge\Desktop\Pract3-copia\Documentation\latex

D:\Users\Jorge\Desktop\Pract3-copia\Documentation\latex>cd /D D:\Users\Jorge\Des
ktop\Pract3-copia\Documentation\latex\

D:\Users\Jorge\Desktop\Pract3-copia\Documentation\latex>del /s /f *.ps *.dvi *.a
ux *.toc *.idx *.ind *.ilg *.log *.out *.brf *.blg *.bbl refman.pdf
Cant find D:\Users\Jorge\Desktop\Pract3-copia\Documentation\latex\*.p
s

D:\Users\Jorge\Desktop\Pract3-copia\Documentation\latex>pdflatex refman
"pdflatex" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

D:\Users\Jorge\Desktop\Pract3-copia\Documentation\latex>echo ----
----

D:\Users\Jorge\Desktop\Pract3-copia\Documentation\latex>makeindex refman.idx
"makeindex" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

D:\Users\Jorge\Desktop\Pract3-copia\Documentation\latex>echo ----
----

D:\Users\Jorge\Desktop\Pract3-copia\Documentation\latex>pdflatex refman
"pdflatex" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

D:\Users\Jorge\Desktop\Pract3-copia\Documentation\latex>setlocal enabledelayedex
pansion

D:\Users\Jorge\Desktop\Pract3-copia\Documentation\latex>set count=8

D:\Users\Jorge\Desktop\Pract3-copia\Documentation\latex>set content=X

D:\Users\Jorge\Desktop\Pract3-copia\Documentation\latex>for /F "tokens=*" %T in
('findstr /C:"Rerun LaTeX" refman.log') do set content="%~T"
FINDSTR: Cant open refman.log

D:\Users\Jorge\Desktop\Pract3-copia\Documentation\latex>if !content! == X for /F
 "tokens=*" %T in ('findstr /C:"Rerun to get cross-references right" refman.log'
) do set content="%~T"
FINDSTR: Cant open refman.log

D:\Users\Jorge\Desktop\Pract3-copia\Documentation\latex>if !content! == X goto :
skip

D:\Users\Jorge\Desktop\Pract3-copia\Documentation\latex>endlocal

D:\Users\Jorge\Desktop\Pract3-copia\Documentation\latex>makeindex refman.idx
"makeindex" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

D:\Users\Jorge\Desktop\Pract3-copia\Documentation\latex>pdflatex refman
"pdflatex" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

D:\Users\Jorge\Desktop\Pract3-copia\Documentation\latex>cd /D D:\Users\Jorge\Des
ktop\Pract3-copia\Documentation\latex

D:\Users\Jorge\Desktop\Pract3-copia\Documentation\latex>set Dir_Old=

D:\Users\Jorge\Desktop\Pract3-copia\Documentation\latex>
```

Comment: I tried to translate the log to english. maybe there is some word missing.

Comment: Does `"pdflatex" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable` mean you have no 'pdflatex' installed?

Comment: I checked, yes it was that. I thoguht the Doxygen installer would install all it need (including this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install a latex distribution to generate a PDF file. I use MikTex. You should have installed the following tools:

- A Latex distribution (e.g. MikTex)
- Ghostscript
- A TCL interpreter (e.g. ActiveTcl)